# J query: Stop fade Out 'message' on mouse over(hover) which is fade in

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var messages = [
        <?php foreach ($offer as $off) { ?>
        [ '<?php echo $off->id; ?>','alert-success-notify_btn','<?php echo $off->description; ?>' ],
        <?php } ?>
    ];
    for(i=0;i<messages.length;i++){
        var message = messages[i];
        $('.notify-message').append('<div id="'+message[0]+'" class="alert '+message[1]+' notify2"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>'+message[2]+'</div>');
        $('#'+message[0]).delay(i * 1 ).fadeIn( "slow");
        $('#'+message[0]).delay(i * 3000 + 2000).fadeOut( "slow");
    }
    $(document).on('click', '.close', function () {$(this).parent().hide();});
});
</script>
```

In this code message will automatically fade In for some seconds and automatically fade Out after seconds are over, I want to stop fade out message on mouse over(hover).

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty straightfoward, what you want to do is:

1. Store the state if an element has been hovered over in the `.data()` object of the element
2. You can then check if this element has been hovered over, before you decide if you want to fade it out

Without knowing your markup, here is what that can be done:

```
for(i=0;i<messages.length;i++){
    var message = messages[i];
    $('.notify-message').append('<div id="'+message[0]+'" class="alert '+message[1]+' notify2"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>'+message[2]+'</div>');

    // Cache message
    var $message = $('#'+message[0]);

    // Fade in message
    $('#'+message[0]).delay(i * 1 ).fadeIn( "slow");

    // Fade out message conditionally
    if ($message.data('hovered'))
      $('#'+message[0]).delay(i * 3000 + 2000).fadeOut( "slow");
}

// Messages are identified with the class `.notify2` as per your markup
// We update the hovered key in the data object of the message onMouseEnter
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.notify2', function() {
    $(this).data('hovered', true);
});
```